# Update database using Sequelize for existing field given in request Node.Js

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

How to update our model only for existing field given by client to our API?

Example:

```
User.update({‘name’: ‘value_1’, {‘email’: ‘value_2’,}.then().catch()
```

I want to automatically update my User model based on what my client give when Requesting my API (if they only provide `name`, then my Model only update the `name` field without updating the `email` field) . Is there any best practice for doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the user you are working with, assign the received parameters and save the user

For example:

```
const user = await User.findByPk(id);
Object.assign(user, params);
await user.save();
```

Comment: Thankyou! `Object.assign`'s keyword helps me alot!